# How to trim prefix in goggle sheets using various conditions

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I have data as follows in excel/google sheets.
Numbers that have a length of 19 characters need to be manipulated in this way
For all strings with a length of 19 last 6 digits need to be trimmed, ( i can easily do it )
and remove the leading prefix which is either 200 or 20000

for example
2005507187528000001 to **5507187528** |
2000017303364000001 to **17303364**

Have no idea what to do to remove the prefix, I tried trimming the last 14 digits to get 20000 or 20055 and using this to determine if I need to take out the first 3 or first 6, but no success.

Please help !!!

thanks

[image]

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add input table and expected output table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A&""; ".{6}$")))
```

---

### update:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(F905&""; "^20+(\d.*)\d{6}")
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly you want to remove the first N characters whether it is 200 or 20000.

**Try:**

```
=IF(LEFT(A2,5)="20000",RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-5),RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-3))
```

Drag down to column.

**Result:**
[image]

**Explanation:**

Using the `LEFT()` function you can extract the first 5 characters. You can then use an `IF()` to check if it is equal to 20000. Then using the Combination of `RIGHT()` and `LEN()` to remove the first N characters. If it is equal to 20000 remove the first 5 characters, if not then remove the first 3 characters.

---

**Using an ArrayFormula:**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="","",IF(LEFT(A2:A,5)="20000",RIGHT(A2:A,LEN(A2:A)-5),RIGHT(A2:A,LEN(A2:A)-3))))
```

Here's a way using arrayformula so you don't have to drag down/copy to cells below. This of course still needs to be adjusted to your range.
[image]

---

**Note:** I have not included the formula to remove the last 6 characters since according to you you already have this, so you can just add this formula to yours.

> For all strings with a length of 19 last 6 digits need to be trimmed,
> ( i can easily do it )

**References:**

- [Remove the First N Characters in a Cell in Google Sheets](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/remove-the-first-n-characters-in-google-sheets/) - Multiple ways to remove the first N characters, refer to this link.
- [LEFT()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094079?hl=en)
- [IF()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en)